# function stored inside array

Tags: php, arrays

i want to call function store inside array but before i do it i want to check if it is function,string or any other type.

please take a look at my code

```
$a=new stdClass();
$array = array(function() {
return "Bhavik Patel";
}, "1213",$a);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_object($value)) {
        echo $value() . "<br/>";
    } else {
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

by doing this i can check if value is object then i call it but if i pass object it gives (pf course this will give error)

my intention is to find if value is function then call it.

Comment: Dear i know how to store function in array. please read carefully what  i trying to do

Comment: @Jack Realized after I closed :)

Comment: can you now remove duplication mark?

Comment: We cannot take that, but don't worry, it won't be closed, and the box you are seeing, is only you who can see, not anyone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check specifically for anonymous functions you can test the value against [`\Closure`](http://php.net/closure) like so:

```
if ($value instanceof \Closure) {
    echo $value(), "\n";
} else {
    echo $value;
}
```

The problem with [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/is_callable) is that if your value is `"explode"`, it will return `true` which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: @BhavikPatel Try `$value = 'explode'; $value();` and you will see what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

is_callable() will help you, but notice that if you pass an array like this

```
array('object or class','method')
```

is_callable() return true, so you'd better to check it isn't an array

```
if (is_callable($value) && !is_array($value)) {.....}
```

see [is_callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

Comment: A string can also be a callable :)

Comment: @Jack yeap, I miss that

Answer (score 0):

Try `[is_callable][1]` in PHP. I have tested it, it works for me.